# Android : which google play service version should be included in the gradle

Tags: android, maven, gradle, google-play-services

I want to add the security provider check in my app as mentioned here
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider

I want to know what should be added to my gradle so that i can access these google apis.
I tried adding `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:17.0.0'`
and it works. But I am jot sure if I have to add the -plus service. I see a list of dependencies for various uses here https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup
I am not sure which is the one that I have to use so that I dont end up adding dependencies which are not required by my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/security/ProviderInstaller is listed under the "basement" artifact, so if you only use the `ProviderInstaller` class you should just need

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.3.0'
```

Note that almost all `com.google.android.gms` artifacts transitively pull in `play-services-basement`, so if you already depend on a `com.google.android.gms` you don't need to list `play-services-basement` explicitly. If you don't use APIs from `play-services-plus`, you should be able to remove your dependency on `play-services-plus` after adding the dep on basement (or any other `com.google.android.gms` artifact that you actually use).

Answer (score 0):

Remove dependencies and see if it still works.